# Entity Frameworks generates huge query and takes a long time to build

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ query with a lot of joins. But when I execute the query EF needs a long time to compile it (around 25 seconds). When I look at the generated SQL I see it uses a lot of UNION ALLs. Why does it do that? Why can't it just generate the joins instead?

The classes are from the database (Database First)

The LINQ query looks like this:

```
    (from persoon in PagedView.Context.PERSOON
    join verhuring in PagedView.Context.VERHURINGEN
        .Where(
            x => x.DatumGeldigTot == null || x.DatumGeldigTot >= OverzichtPersonenSearch.ReferentieDatum)
    on persoon.ComputerNr equals verhuring.PersoonsID into a
    from verhuring in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join eenheid in PagedView.Context.EENHEID
    on verhuring.Eenheid equals eenheid.ComputerNr into b
    from eenheid in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join data in PagedView.Context.DATA
    on persoon.ComputerNr equals data.COMPUTERNR into c
    join huur in PagedView.Context.HUURPRIJSM
    on persoon.ComputerNr equals huur.PERSOON into d
    from mtb in d.OrderByDescending(x => x.INVOEGE).GroupBy(x => x.PERSOON).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).DefaultIfEmpty()
    join insch in PagedView.Context.INSCHRIJVINGEN
    on persoon.ComputerNr equals insch.PERSOONSID into e
    from insch in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join att in PagedView.Context.ATTESTEN
    on persoon.ComputerNr equals att.COMPUTERNR into f
    select new PersoonDto
    {
        ComputerNr = persoon.ComputerNr,
        EIGENREF = persoon.EIGENREF,
        NAAM = persoon.NAAM,
        ADRES = persoon.ADRES,
        LANDCODE = persoon.LANDCODE,
        POSTNR = persoon.POSTNR,
        TELEFOON = persoon.TELEFOON,
        EMAIL = persoon.EMAIL,
        RIJKSREGISTER = persoon.RIJKSREGISTER,
        SOORT_PERSOON = persoon.SOORT_PERSOON,
        GESLACHT = persoon.GESLACHT,
        DATUM = persoon.DATUM,
        FAMILIENAAM = persoon.FAMILIENAAM,
        VOORNAAM = persoon.VOORNAAM,
        STRAAT = persoon.STRAAT,
        NR = persoon.NR,
        BUSNR = persoon.BUSNR,
        Website = persoon.Website,
        IsActief = persoon.IsActief,
        Verhuringen = persoon.Verhuringen,
        POSTNRS = persoon.POSTNRS,
        BANKREKENING_IBAN = persoon.BANKREKENING_IBAN,
        GEBOORTELAND = persoon.GEBOORTELAND,
        GEBOORTEPLAATS = persoon.GEBOORTEPLAATS,
        GEBOORTEDATUM = persoon.GEBOORTEDATUM,
        BANKREKENINGOGM = persoon.BANKREKENINGOGM,
        Nationaliteit = persoon.Nationaliteit,
        DUBIEUZEHUURDER = persoon.DUBIEUZEHUURDER,
        BEROEP = persoon.BEROEP,
        DATA = c.ToList(),
        MaandelijksHuurBedrag = mtb.MTEBETEUR,
        CATEGORIE = persoon.CATEGORIE,
        FacRequest = persoon.FacRequest,
        Inschrijvingen = insch,
        ATTESTEN = f.ToList(),
        Een = eenheid
    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.ComputerNr).GroupBy(x => x.ComputerNr).Select(x=> x.FirstOrDefault())
```

The SQL code it then generates looks like this: [SQL query](http://pastebin.com/XwA47Srd)

EDIT: I am breaking down my query bit by bit but it still generates a lot of unnecessary data:

```
from persoon in PagedView.Context.PERSOON
join verhuring in PagedView.Context.VERHURINGEN.Select(x => new 
    {
        DatumGeldigTot = x.DatumGeldigTot,
        Eenheid = x.Eenheid,
        PersoonsID = x.PersoonsID
    })
    .Where(
        x => x.DatumGeldigTot == null || x.DatumGeldigTot >= OverzichtPersonenSearch.ReferentieDatum)
on persoon.ComputerNr equals verhuring.PersoonsID into a
from verhuring in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new PersoonDto
                {
                    ComputerNr                         = persoon.ComputerNr,
                    EIGENREF                           = persoon.EIGENREF,
                    NAAM                               = persoon.NAAM,
                    ADRES                              = persoon.ADRES,
                    LANDCODE                           = persoon.LANDCODE,
                    POSTNR                             = persoon.POSTNR,
                    TELEFOON                           = persoon.TELEFOON,
                    EMAIL                              = persoon.EMAIL,
                    RIJKSREGISTER                      = persoon.RIJKSREGISTER,
                    GESLACHT                           = persoon.GESLACHT,
                    DATUM                              = persoon.DATUM,
                    FAMILIENAAM                        = persoon.FAMILIENAAM,
                    VOORNAAM                           = persoon.VOORNAAM,
                    STRAAT                             = persoon.STRAAT,
                    NR                                 = persoon.NR,
                    BUSNR                              = persoon.BUSNR,
                    Website                            = persoon.Website,
                    IsActief                           = persoon.IsActief,
                    Verhuringen                        = persoon.Verhuringen,
                    POSTNRS                            = persoon.POSTNRS,
                    BANKREKENING_IBAN                  = persoon.BANKREKENING_IBAN,
                    GEBOORTELAND                       = persoon.GEBOORTELAND,
                    GEBOORTEPLAATS                     = persoon.GEBOORTEPLAATS,
                    GEBOORTEDATUM                      = persoon.GEBOORTEDATUM,
                    BANKREKENINGOGM                    = persoon.BANKREKENINGOGM,
                    Nationaliteit                      = persoon.Nationaliteit,
                    DUBIEUZEHUURDER                    = persoon.DUBIEUZEHUURDER,
                    BEROEP                             = persoon.BEROEP
                }
```

All this still becomes this [sql query](http://pastebin.com/rTKumGUr). Even though I only need 3 properties from `verhuringen` it gets every column in the table.

Comment: Try to create a DB View (or views).

Comment: Generating unions can be significantly faster than "just generating joins", because joins *multiply* the number of returned rows, while unions only *add* returned rows. You could verify that by writing the query manually as pure joins. Since you collect data mainly as a "star" around `persoon` you can easily break it down in multiple queries, which no doubt will be considerably faster. It's not always true that one query is faster than multiple queries.

Comment: Use a stored procedure instead